# Angular i18n: Get all locales at runtime

Tags: angular, localization, angular-i18n

I have an app that is localized using angular-i18n to which I want to add a language switch button. This is working, however, the available languages are hard-coded, i.e. I have to specify the languages in code that the app was translated to.

Is there a way to get a list of all available locales (or in other words: is it possible to get the names of all the folders in the `dist` directory at runtime?)

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your question but...

I highly recommend Transoloco for Angular, instead of `angular-i18n`:

https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/

You can inject the `TransoloService` and call `getAvailableLangs` from their language API:

https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/docs/language-api#getavailablelangs

Comment: I'm open for other frameworks but after a quick glimpse, this seems a little verbose; In angular-i18n I can simply write `$localize`XYZ`` whereas for transloco I need to inject the service anytime, is that correct?

Comment: Well, you can declaratively add translations (with context) in the template. Or alternatively, inject a service and translate imperatively in the component class.

Comment: I don't mean templates, I mean other files that are not necessarily services or components where I can't simply inject another service. I have a couple of those in said project, for example model classes or utility functions

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to provide a country selector for users, then locales selector.

I think you can use this [lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-locale-map)
You can see that it includes many countries & locales, even currencies.
For my situation, I need to provide a way for users to specify their country and locales.

With this lib, you can make your own locale or country selector.

```
const clm = require('country-locale-map');

clm.getAllCountries();

clm.getCountryByAlpha2('CA'); 

/*returns 

    {
        "name":"Canada",
        "alpha2":"CA",
        "alpha3":"CAN",
        "numeric":"124",
        "locales":["en_CA","fr_CA"],
        "default_locale":"en_CA",
        "currency":"CAD",
        "languages":["en","fr"],
        "capital":"Ottawa",
        "emoji":"",
        "emojiU":"U+1F1E8 U+1F1E6",
        "fips":"CA",
        "internet":"CA",
        "continent":"Americas",
        "region":"North America"
    }

*/
```

**Note:**

The lib only can be used on the backend side.